# how to update 2 attributes with one radio button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm not sure if I'm just stuck in a jQuery mindset but is there a way to update 2 model attributes with one radio button? Currently I have 2 radio buttons with one hidden. The visible one checks the second with an @click event that gets the next input and sets it to true.

```
var app = new Vue({

  data: {
    order: { 
      amount: 
      type:
    }
  },

  methods: {
    selectType: function(e) {
      e.currentTarget.getElementSibling.checked = true;
    }
  }
}); 

<form>
  <input type="radio" v-model="order.amount" value=15 @click="selectType">$15</input><br>
  <input type="radio" v-model="order.type" value="small" style="display:none">

  <input type="radio" v-model="order.amount" value=15 @click="selectType">$15</input><br>
  <input type="radio" v-model="order.type" value="med" style="display:none" @click="selectType">

  <input type="radio" v-model="order.amount" value=20 >$20</input><br>
  <input type="radio" v-model="order.type" value="large" style="display:none">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand it, the `v-model` syntax is best for binding a single value. You could try to somehow make the value a JSON string and then decode it... but that sounds like a bad idea. Here are three ideas:

## Using JQuery and Vue

Instead, you could give the radio buttons attributes for each value you want, and then parse out those attributes on the click callback. For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="rad" btn-amount="10" btn-type="small" @click="selectType($event)">$15 <br>
<input type="radio" name="rad" btn-amount="15" btn-type="med" @click="selectType">$15<br>
<input type="radio" name="rad" btn-amount="20" btn-type="large" @click="selectType">$20<br>
```

and then a method:

```
selectType: function(e) {
  this.order.amount = $(e.currentTarget).attr('btn-amount');
  this.order.type = $(e.currentTarget).attr('btn-type');
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/vkz497y9/) showing it in action.

## Using Vue only

Alternatively, you could move the data for the options into the vue instance, rather than placing them on on the radio buttons. For example, add an `options` array to the data, and iterate over it in the HTML to create the buttons

```
<div v-for="option in options">
  <input type="radio" name="rad" @click="selectType(option)">${{ option.amount }}
</div>
```

Notice that you can pass the current `option` in the for loop to the click handler! That means you can write `selectType` as:

```
selectType: function(option) {
  this.order = option;
}
```

This is very clean, and what I recommend if you plan on keeping the radio-button functionality simple.

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/cgfLwwkz/) showing it in action.

## Using Vue Components

But, if you plan on making things more complex you may want to encapsulate the radio button functionality into a component.

Consider the template:

```
<template id="radio-order">
  <div>
    <input type="radio" :name="group" @click="setOrder">${{ amount }}
  </div>
</template>
```

and its associated component:

```
Vue.component('radio-order', {
  template: '#radio-order',

  props: ['group', 'amount', 'type'],

  methods: {
    'setOrder': function() {
      this.$dispatch('set-order', {
        amount: this.amount,
        type: this.type
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Now you can make `<radio-order>` components that dispatch a `set-order` event when clicked. The parent instance can listen for these events and act appropriately.

Admittedly, this method is more verbose. But, if you're thinking of implementing more complex functionality, it's probably the way to go.

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/aLk0mqwk/) of it in action.

Of course, there are many more ways to solve the problem, but I hope these ideas help!